# How to programmatically compile a c code from a c# code using mingw32-gcc compiler

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to compile a C code from c# programmatically. I am trying but i have not found any solution yet. Here is my code.

```
try {
    var info = new ProcessStartInfo {
        FileName = "cmd.exe",
        Arguments = "mingw32-gcc -o a Test.c"
    };
    var process = new Process { StartInfo = info };
    bool start = process.Start();

    process.WaitForExit();
    if (start) {
        Console.WriteLine("done");
    }
} catch (Exception) {
    Console.WriteLine("Not done");
}
```

I am using VS2010 in windows 7 and I have installed mingw32-gcc and my environment variable for mingw32-gcc is **C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin**
Any Help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So that we understand the context: What do you intend to do with the resulting C code?

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: I am building a webbased online judge for my semester final project.So normally there should be an option where contestent can submit there code. So I have to take the submitted code and save into a .c file than have to compile it and provide feedback to the contestant. **I have compile a c code in a desktop application in java** But facing problem in C#. Thanks

Comment: +1 for finally allowing [C-injection](http://xkcd.com/327/) on a website. I hate SQL.

Comment: What's the error you got and what the environment variable you talk about? Or does it simply never end (which is what I expect, since you open up a command prompt). Have you tried with `Filename` set to the actual path of mingw32-gcc.exe, no need to call `cmd.exe`? Make sure to include ".exe".

Comment: @HenkHolterman A few competitive programming websites compile (with `gcc` et. al.) and execute arbitrary code, and they same to do it pretty securely. The key is sandboxing.

Comment: OK, environmentvariable shortens path to compile or to do something. Like we start cmd.exe just typing cmd in the Run with was actually %SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe. so it was added to our pc's environment variable. I used mingw32-gcc.exe. But no result. @Abel. Regards. It is easy for me to use linux. I am master of it. But asp.net MVC3 makes thing easier. So i use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling the cmd.exe program is not necessary. You can directly call the mingw32-gcc.exe program with arguments.

Edit:

```
string szMgwGCCPath = "C:\\mingw32\\bin\\mingw32-gcc.exe"; // Example of location
string szArguments = " -c main.c -o main.exe"; // Example of arguments
ProcessStartInfo gccStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(szMgwGCCPath , szArguments );
gccStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Process.Start(gccStartInfo );
```

Regards

Comment: Directly calling mingw32-gcc.exe with arguments did not solve my problem man.Can you be specific? Thanks for replying. Regards

Comment: @ForhadHussain: can you be specific with "did not solve my problem"? Errors, locks, what? Grifos is right in that you should not call "cmd.exe".

Comment: Right @Abel i did not call cmd.exe then. But my program is now working correctly because i have edited it. Thanks you all.

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
Process process = Process.Start(
         @"C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\mingw32-gcc.exe", "-o a Test.c");
```

Comment: @YoryeNathan I wouldn't really call `mingw32` something to enjoy.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Doesn't matter, he should get the credit and the thank you if the answer helped the OP.

Comment: @YoryeNathan It seems the sarcasm train was an express.